# switching from gl_FragColor to "out" value nothing is rendered

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm upgrading a lot of my old OpenGL code including a fragment shader and trying to remove the reference to *gl_FragColor* doesn't seem to work.

```
#version 330

varying vec2 uvs;
uniform vec3 cameraPos;
uniform vec4 brushColor;
uniform sampler2D meshTexture;
uniform sampler2D paintTexture;
uniform int paintFboWidth;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 meshColor; // added this

void main() {
    vec2 paintUvs = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x/paintFboWidth, gl_FragCoord.y/paintFboWidth);
    float paintIntensity = texture(paintTexture, paintUvs).r;
    vec4 meshColor = texture(meshTexture, uvs);
    vec3 diffuseColor = mix(meshColor.rgb, brushColor.rgb, paintIntensity);

    meshColor = vec4(diffuseColor, 0); // added this
    //gl_FragData[0] = vec4(diffuseColor, 0); // trying to remove this
}
```

From what I understand, if I switch to an *out* variable it will just work, but when I write to *meshColor* instead of *gl_FragData[0]* I don't see anything displayed on the screen and no GL error.

Do I need to do anything else in the shader or outside in C++ code to use this out variable?

Comment: Try "out vec4 meshColor" instead of  layout(location = 0) out vec4 meshColor;

Comment: In glsl version 3.30 a fragment shader input is specified by the kyword `in` rather than `varying`. So it has to be `in vec2 uvs;`

Comment: Removing the layout(...) stuff doesn't help.  And I think I would need that syntax eventually for multiple color attachments.  Also changing "varying" to "in" doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was shadowing a parameter in the shader so it wasn't actually writing to the output variable.

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 meshColor;
...
    vec4 meshColor = texture(meshTexture, uvs);
    ...

    meshColor = vec4(diffuseColor, 0); // writing to the local instance
}
```